# Translating ACF fields with WPML - only checkbox field values not showing up | WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, translation, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

I have used ACF fields and WPML to make multilingual website. Everything works okay (all the other acf fields are being correctly translated & shown), but checkbox field values are being displayed as just empty white area. It works OK on main language. Problem only occurs on translated languages.

Image of what I need:

[image: figure]

As you can notice, the fields are there (but values are not) note that their content is still being displayed on webpage..just that you cant see values on the back-end and cant edit them because of that.

WP 4.4, ACF 5.3.4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FIXED!!

Problem was: When duplicating ACF fields, the checkbox choices (values) weren't duplicated so the fields were left empty to begin with - thats why they didn't appear. There was nothing to show on other languages.

Solution was: Copy the checkbox values from original language to other languages manually.